# What is a functional screen?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, pathogenesis, host-pathogen-interaction

I was going through [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11872842) paper, but did not understand a term. 
What is the meaning of functional screen?

(I am not a biology student, I don't understand much, and a small simple explanation would be enough)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the abstract of the linked article [(Guttman, 2002)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11872842):

> We used an in vivo genetic screen to identify 13 effectors [...]. Although sharing little overall homology, the amino-terminal regions of these effectors had strikingly similar amino acid compositions.

And from the body:

> The screen relied on the type III secretion signal and the endogenous promoter of the hop gene and was thus highly specific.

Hence, the authors search and identify proteins with a secretory signal under the regulation of a hop promoter. A ***functional [screen](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/genetic+screening)*** in this paper refers to the ***analysis of protein samples to detect the presence of proteins with a particular function***.